# Can we tune an entanglement between photons to get these interference fringes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-entanglement

I am reading [this](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_%28Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry%29/Quantum_Tutorials_%28Rioux%29/Quantum_Fundamentals/25%3A_Double%E2%80%90Slit_Experiment_with_Polarized_Light) article, where
the author uses the Jones formalism to describe the interference with polarizers.

The first one is vertical and the angle of the other can vary. This gives different patterns.
It goes from perfect fringe visibility when they are parallel to no fringe if orthogonal.
Intermediate visibility may be observed.
I read in wikipedia that this Jones formalism (extended to stokes formalism) is the same that the quantum mechanic formalism for 2 level systems,and that the density matrix corresponds to the stokes parameters.

So I wonder if every pattern obtained with 2 polarizers can be gotten with one of 2 entangled photons.
(its  density matrix being obtained by tracing out a couple of photons pure density matrix). A maximally entangled pair will lead Bob to see no interference in YDSE, interference if the photons are not correlated, interference patterns in  between.

Comment: it would help if you could describe a bit better the setup in the question itself, and even more if you could include some math. So you have a single photon passing through the two slits. The slits have polarizer, which thus can affect the indistinguishability of the two paths. I don't understand where the pair of entangled photons comes from in the discussion

Comment: In the article there are polarizers.He gets different patterns depending on polarizers.I consider now that there are no polarizers.I want to get the same patterns with particles belonging to pairs to get these patterns. when the polarizers were orthogona there was no fringe. i get the same with particles belonging to Bell pairs. when the polarizers were parallel there were interferences that i get without polarizers with particles not entangled with the other. when the angle were say pi/8 i wonder how to tune the degree of entanglement to ger the same pattern same fringe visibility

Comment: I still don't understand how you are reaching these conclusions. Are you saying this based on some actual math? If so, you should show it, that would certainly help understand what you are talking about. If instead of a single photon in two slits you have a pair of (polarization?) entangled photons each passing through a slit, the scenario is very different, so you should clarify how you are saying you get the same results

Comment: Please look at the new question i asked. the title is "Interferometry with photons in a mixed state: how to calculate the fringe visibility". here there is no polarizer but reduced fringe visibility. there is an angle alpha in the density matrx. in the article with polarizers there is also reduced visibility and an angle theta. i wonder if the same pattern may be found with a correct relation between alpha and theta.